# ¿Cómo eliminar el borde negro que aparece en un botón al pulsarlo?

Tags: html, css

Hace poco, creo que Google Chrome debió actualizar la interfaz, o por así decirlo, los estilos de las etiquetas. Ahora, cuando se pulsa un botón, aparece un borde negro alrededor. Dejo  ejemplo. Lo que quiero es que ese borde negro no aparezca al hacer click encima, o que haga otra acción, pero que eso desaparezca

```css
.button5 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button5">Boton</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente tendrías que quitarle la opción `border: 2px solid #555555;`, haciendo que quede de la siguiente forma, sin el borde negro.

Y para quitar el recuadro al pulsarlo, añadir `outline: none` en la clase `button5`.

```css
.button5 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
}

.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button5">Boton</button>
```